# Does the present participle "flooding back" function as adverbial in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

There are some puzzling points between complements and adverbials.

> [When he told me his name, it all came flooding back.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/flood-back)

Should "flooding back" in the upper sentence be a present participle functioning as a adverbial to modify "came"?

Should "flooding back" in the under sentence be a present participle as a complement of object "them"?

> [A song brought them flooding back](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2023/mar/29/a-moment-that-changed-me-road-accident-song-memories-childhood).

As a verb,"flooding" should have a subject,so the subject should be "them" not "A song",isn't?

Comment: The subject of ***came** [flooding] **back*** is "it" - which isn't exactly as generic as the "existential it" in ***It's raining***, but it's pretty vague. Preceding text will probably clarify exactly what "it" refers to (memories of some specific past trauma, presumably).

Comment: No, it's not adverbial. "Come" is a catenative verb and the clause "flooding back" is its catenative **complement**. You already have an answer to your second question.

Comment: **Them** is the memories mentioned in the previous sentence.

Comment: Near-duplicate to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/334788/what-kind-of-part-of-speech-is-the-flooding-in-a-song-brought-them-flooding-b